# Is it possible to avoid page reload after accept of an activex object

Tags: activex, html, reload

I have a multi-page flow of webpages (jsp).
After the user have done a lot of work i need to use an activex component, if not pressent on the machine the user is presented yellow bar at the top to accept the component, after accepting the page is reloaded and the user must repeat all the work, do to the fact that the page is reloaed - can this be avoided?

Comment: The multi-page jsp flow is embedded in a iframe. The an activex component is accepted in the yellow bar, the reload or re-rendering of the page result in a GET for the iframes contents. It is this GET that i would like to avoid not the re-rendering itself.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to keep from reloading the page after dealing with the yellow bar, but there are ways you can detect if the activex control is installed or not, and then install it with a .exe or .msi (requires the user to download it) which is then available immediately after installation.

It's not an easy thing to get right, but there are some posts about it here:
http://colonelpanic.net/2009/01/detecting-the-version-of-an-activex-ie-browser-plugin/